# Compression of char size integer by removing leading zeroes

Tags: c, binary, compression

I compressed a char array by removing leading zeros from integer data and packed them tightly (without leaving spaces bit-wise). I wish to decompress it to get my original data back. The data is 8-bit and can have any number of zeros ranging from 0 to 8. I cannot exceed the 8 bit limit to store flags and cannot send another string of data as the communication speed is not reliable. I am working in C and removed the zeros by counting them and shifting.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.:-)

Comment: `leading zeros from integer data`...how is that? what is your delimiter then?

Comment: Delimiter is 1. Its simply a case of counting leading zeros in binary data and then shifting it by the count to get the output which always starts with a 1

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear. Are you compressing, for instance, both `{255, 0}` and `{0, 255}` to `{255}`? There is no way to distinguish one from the other without any external data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice try, with just few corrections. You have to store a mark that will give you a clue how long was original value so you can decompress it back. Sure thing, there is nothing new under the moon so you can reuse such thing as **VarInt**:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints

It's wide-spread practice and supported in many libs at broad range of lanuages